# Где docker хранит контейнеры?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

У меня redmine установлен на сервере в двух контейнерах:

- postgresql-redmine
- redmine

Хочу перенести их, запустить в другом месте, и сделать резервную копию. В документации ясно написано, что контейнеры создаются в том числе для переноса, однако инструкций как это делается я не нашёл. Нашёл, что docker хранит свои файлы в директории /var/lib/docker однако там у меня много тысяч файлов на 4 GB, а мои контейнеры - намного меньше, не хотелось бы таскать всё что есть в этой директории

Comment: Вы изначально при запуске контейнеров не создавали volumes на хостовую машину `docker run -v /path/to/host/data::/var/lib/postgresql`?

Comment: скорее всего создавал, я по инструкции настраивал: https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redmine

Comment: Да, в доках написано `--volume=/srv/docker/redmine/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql`. Когда контейнер запускался директория  `/srv/docker/redmine/postgresql` должна была создаться автоматически. Посмотрите, что там или `sudo docker inspect --format '{{ .Volumes }}' postgresql-redmine`. Достаточно заархивировать её, перенести на новый сервер и разархивировать. Путь разархиварования, не имеет значение, ибо директория, как вы уже заметили, задаётся через volume.  Далее, на новой машине подтянуть  образ контейнера желательно той же версии: `docker pull quay.io/sameersbn/postgresql:latest`

Comment: Собственно, запускаем postgres-контейнер, но без переменных окружения - нам же не нужно вновь создавать БД и пользователя: `docker run --name=postgresql-redmine -d --volume=/srv/docker/redmine/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql  quay.io/sameersbn/postgresql:latest`. C redmine аналогично. Архивируем `/srv/docker/redmine/redmine`, переносим и запускаем `docker run --name=redmine -d --link=postgresql-redmine:postgresql -p 10083:80 -e 'REDMINE_PORT=10083' -v /srv/docker/redmine/redmine:/home/redmine/data quay.io/sameersbn/redmine`

Comment: Да, перед архивированием контейнеры необходимо остановить `docker stop redmine postgresql-redmine`, а потому можно запустить вновь `docker stop postgresql-redmine redmine`.

Comment: Путей /srv/docker/ на хост-машине нет, видимо это пути внутри контейнера. А вот по /var/lib/postgresql хранятся базы postgres, вот только базы редмайна там нет, там только базы, которые крутятся на хост-машине. Папка /home/redmine/data так же существует, но она пуста. Видимо туда сохраняются файлы, прикреплённые к задачам редмайна, но у нас файлов нет. Я так это понял

Comment: `Путей /srv/docker/ на хост-машине нет`. Если вы делали всё по инструкции, то довольно странно. Запись опции `--volume=/srv/docker/redmine/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql` означает, что слева путь до директории с данными вашей хост-машины, а справа - путь внутри контейнера. Кроме того, если вы данную опцию не указали, то задействованы внутренние volumes (по умолчанию), ибо разработчик `sameersbn` любезно указал это [в конфиге](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-postgresql/blob/master/Dockerfile#L25).

Comment: Узнать, в какой директории хранятся volumes по умолчанию можно через `docker inspect --format '{{ .Volumes }}' postgresql-redmine`. Там будет указано два volumes до `/run/postgresql` и `/var/lib/postgresql`. Именно последний путь нас интересует. Все volumes хранятся в `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<хэш volume>/_data` Таким образом, можно просто исследовав все директории в `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` и найти необходимый, но через `docker inspect` наглядней - сразу покажет где что лежит. Механизм создание volumes таков:

Comment: если вы указываете непосредственно в опциях в момент запуска контейнера (`docker run -v /host/to/path/data:/container/to/path/data`) и аналогичный путь `/container/to/path/data` указан в конфиге, как volume по умолчанию, то вы переопределяете директорию на хост-машине, т.е. не где-то там `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<хэш volume>/_data` (автоматически определяет сам docker), а в конкретное меcто куда вы сами указали, к примеру: `/srv/docker/redmine/postgresql`.

Comment: Аналогично и для redmine смотрим: `docker inspect --format '{{ .Volumes }}' redmine`, где `redmine`- это имя запущенного контейнера/процесса (не путать с названием образа контейнера `quay.io/sameersbn/redmine` + его тег, в данном случае это версия redmine). Все ваши запущенные на текущий момент контейнеры можно посмотреть через команду `docker ps -a`

Comment: Где хранятся volumes нашёл, как их теперь перенести?
Попробовал сделать свои образы из контейнеров, посредством команды docker commit <id контейнера> <имя образа> Но при попытке развернуть на другой машине, redmine работать отказался, если вывести в консоль его вывод, получаю следующую ошибку:
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.8.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:369:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.2.21) ruby' in the gems available

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30852/discussion-between-romeo-and--).

Comment: У вас вроде кармы достаточно. Айда в чат.

Comment: Скомпилировал нашу с вами беседу и разместил в ответе. Я дополнительно привёл ещё соображения почему возникает ошибка Ruby и ещё кое-что.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В приведённой вами [инструкции](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redmine#quick-start) видно, что контейнер запускается с опцией

```
--volume=/srv/docker/redmine/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
```

,где `<путь до директории с данными на хосте>:<путь до директории с данными в контейнере>`

> В момент монтирования происходит затирание данных в контейнере, если те присутствовали по этому пути.

Если опция `--volume` не была указана, то docker автоматически создаёт volumes исходя из параметров указанных в конфигурационном файле Dockerfile.

Если обратиться к [исходникам образа для PostgreSQL](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-postgresql/blob/master/Dockerfile#L25), то можно заметить, что это два volumes: `/var/lib/postgresql` и `/run/postgresql`. По первому пути расположены данные postgres. Собственно, они нас и интересуют.

Узнать всю информацию про volumes отдельно взятого контейнера можно командой

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .Volumes }}' <имя контейнера>
```

Данные возвращаются в json-формате, а потому предусмотрена возможность фильтрации/поиска через опцию `--format`

Все volumes для которых не указан путь расположения на хосте (левая часть `/host/path/to/data:/container/to/data`) хранятся в директории `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<хэш volume>/_data/`. Таким образом, можно просто исследовав все директории в /var/lib/docker/volumes/ и найти необходимый.

> Если левая часть указана, а правая совпадает с volumes, которые указаны в Dockerfile (volumes by default), то происходит переопределение директории на хосте. Зачем нам два волиума с одинковыми данными на хосте (`/var/lib/docker/volumes/<хэш volume>/_data/` и `/host/path/to/data`), правда?

Как уже было отмечено @dmitrz, пока не существует возможности управлять volumes уже на поднятых контейнерах, также как и линковать. Первая проблема должна уже очень скоро решиться.

#### Команда commit

Volume является отдельной сущностью и потому не попадает в commit. Вот что говорит [официальная документация](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/commit/).

> The commit operation will not include any data contained in volumes mounted inside the container.

И ещё.

> Вообще смущает наличие двух методов создания образов: файлами конфигурации и коммитами.

Файл конфигурации задаёт изначальную конфигурацию контейнера в момент запуска, а коммит сохраняет состояние на момент коммита. Если, к примеру, волиумы не задавать (не в конфиге и не при запуске), то состояние контейнера будет меняться (писаться данные будут именно в него). Возможно, у вас может возникнуть ситуация, когда нужно подправить конфиг postgres или ещё что-то сделать внутри контейнера, то с помощью команды `docker exec -it postgresql bash` вы можете зайти внутрь. Далее, все сделанные изменения вы можете закоммитить в образ, чтобы запуская контейнер где-нибудь ещё из этого образа не повторять все эти действия. Но такой подход сомнительный. Лучше сделать правки в основном конфиге `Dockerfile`.

#### Ошибка в версии Ruby

В docker существует такое понятие, как entrypoint. Обычно это shell-скрипт, который дёргается при запуске `docker run` или `docker start`. Если посмотреть [листинг entrypoint.sh для redmine](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redmine/blob/master/entrypoint.sh#L542), то можно заметить установку плагинов (bundles) для redmine. Далее, если файла `${REDMINE_DATA_DIR}/tmp/plugins.sha1` не существует, то происходит установка плагинов. Обратите внимание на переменную `${REDMINE_DATA_DIR}` и посмотрите в [Dockerfile для redmine](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redmine/blob/master/Dockerfile#L41), т.е. `REDMINE_DATA_DIR` входит в волиум. Вспоминаем, что при коммите данные волиума не заносятся в образ. Когда закоммиченый контейнер запускается на новой машине видимо возникает конфликт старой версии redmine и устанавливаемых вновь плагинов.

Если данные redmine критичны (`/srv/docker/redmine/redmine:/home/redmine/data`), то их обязательно нужно перенести на новую машину. Далее, поднять либо закоммиченый образ, либо загрузить контейнер с уже новой версией redmine по [той инструкции](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redmine#quick-start).

Можете ознакомится со всеми [**доступными версиями**](https://quay.io/repository/sameersbn/redmine?tab=tags) redmine образов от sameersbn.

Что касается PostgreSQL контейнера, то его данные (`/srv/docker/redmine/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql`) обязательно необходимо перенести.

[**Список доступных версий postgres образов**](https://quay.io/repository/sameersbn/postgresql?tab=tags)  от sameersbn.

#### Загрузка образов

Загрузка образов из registry (https://hub.docker.com/, https://quay.io/, можно даже [поднять локальный](https://docs.docker.com/registry/)) осуществляется с помощь команды

```
docker pull <имя образа>:<тег образа>
```

, где тег - это, как правило, версия софта, который находится в этом образе.

Запуск контейнера происходит командой

```
docker run --name <имя контейнера> -d <имя образа>:<тег образа>
```

Если образа с таким именем и тегом на локальной машине нет, то прозрачно срабатывает команда `docker pull`, т.е. образ ищется на удалённых registry.

Answer (score 1):

Разделы (volumes) в докере существуют отдельно от контейнеров и в данный момент нету у него управления разделами (management volumes).
Так же нет средств миграции разделов между другими машинами, разделы существуют локально, в отличии от контейнеров из которых можно сделать образ и переместить его.

Для решение это задачи необходимо найти папку которая монтируется как раздел в контейнер

> docker inspect <ИМЯ_КОНТЕЙНЕРА> # И найти секцию Volumes

зайти в эту папку и скопировать вручную эти файлы на другую машину, например в папку /data/

Затем на другой машине запустить из образа контейнер и примонтировать пересенные данные:

> docker run -d -v /data/:<РАЗДЕЛ_КОНТЕЙНЕРА> <ОБРАЗ>

Comment: похоже на правду, только у меня почему-то после сборки redmine не запускается, пишет nginx 502 bad geteway, но ответ скорее всего верный, во всяком случае я нашёл базу postgres и скопировал, так что теперь всяко не пропадёт. Как докопаюсь до сути - скорее всего отмечу как верный

Comment: всё заработало! конейнер с postgres пришлось запускать свой, который я создал через:
docker commit <id контейнера> <имя образа>

docker save имя_образа > ~/transfer.tar
docker load < /tmp/transfer.tar
т.к. данные постгреса корректно работают только с той версией, под которой были созданы.