# Перенос Docker контейнера с данными

Tags: docker

Хочу выяснить момент с переносом Docker контейнера с данными.

Делаю следующее поднял 2 сервера Ubuntu 16.04.
На обоих поднял Docker.

На первом сделал контейнер с PostgreSQL, создал несколько тестовых баз, таблиц. Далее делаю по инструкции commit - save - load(на втором сервере) данных которые я менял в PostgreSQL - нет.

Ладно, думаю буду пробовать export/import - после этих процедур, на втором сервере создается контейнер но не стартует.

И вот сижу в недоумении, что не так? Может я не так понимаю технологию Dockera?

Помогите, читал этот пост: [Где docker хранит контейнеры?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462113/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-docker-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B), и запутался еще больше. Если есть save/load и export/import (разница мне тоже не ясна), зачем все эти "танцы с бубном" с переносом "volumes"?

Comment: [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/721063/edit), а не комментировать.

Answer (score 2):

команды `save`/`load` сохраняют/восстанавливают **образ** (image), а команды `export`/`import` сохраняют/восстанавливают **контейнер** (container).

если заглянуть внутрь создаваемых файлов, то видно, что архив с **контейнером** (создаваемый командой `export`) представляет собой всего лишь «банальную» файловую систему, которая и используется в качестве корневой для запускаемого процесса (на всякий случай напомню: программа docker именно и предназначена для запуска **одного** процесса в изолированном окружении, т.е. «в контейнере»).

а архив с **образом** (создаваемый командой `save`) содержит **и** (вложенный) архив с файловой системой (их может быть даже несколько — это т.н. *слои* (layers)) **и** дополнительную мета-информацию (файлы `manifest.json`, `repositories` и т.п.):

```
$ docker save debian:6 | tar -tv
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2016-02-17 00:25 9542fcf2cddff07fa6446c570f7190fa7e4a3b474ce1109e3212f01528707817/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               3 2016-02-17 00:25 9542fcf2cddff07fa6446c570f7190fa7e4a3b474ce1109e3212f01528707817/VERSION
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             393 2016-02-17 00:25 9542fcf2cddff07fa6446c570f7190fa7e4a3b474ce1109e3212f01528707817/json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0        81400832 2016-02-17 00:25 9542fcf2cddff07fa6446c570f7190fa7e4a3b474ce1109e3212f01528707817/layer.tar
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1391 2016-02-17 00:25 a873733ef58132fcb5382ea187454f7370d26d7264a2d42026d65f46ac4d8bac.json
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2016-02-17 00:25 ee4d403db69dd90b3709c55b937d1c4245de8bb11b809189b86b412167ca6e77/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               3 2016-02-17 00:25 ee4d403db69dd90b3709c55b937d1c4245de8bb11b809189b86b412167ca6e77/VERSION
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1084 2016-02-17 00:25 ee4d403db69dd90b3709c55b937d1c4245de8bb11b809189b86b412167ca6e77/json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1024 2016-02-17 00:25 ee4d403db69dd90b3709c55b937d1c4245de8bb11b809189b86b412167ca6e77/layer.tar
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             274 1970-01-01 03:00 manifest.json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0              84 1970-01-01 03:00 repositories
```

---

команда `commit` служит для создания образа из указанного контейнера. процесс, работающий «внутри контейнера», перед выполнением команды имеет смысл остановить — например, если это процесс сервера баз данных, то при остановке он должен сохранить всю информацию из оперативной памяти в соответствующие файлы.

---

*volume* же — это монтируемый внутрь запускаемого контейнера каталог вашей локальной машины. содержимое этого каталога доступно процессу, запущенному «в контейнере» (только для чтения или для чтения/записи — вы [определяете сами соответствующей опцией при запуске контейнера](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/)).

если вы подключаете какой-нибудь каталог, а процессу «внутри контейнера», например, серверу баз данных, говорите создать базу данных именно в подключенном каталоге, то даже после удаления контейнера все файлы базы данных сохранятся у вас в локальном каталоге.

*volume* может быть указан либо в командной строке при запусе контейнера, либо в *dockerfile*, либо [создан как отдельная сущность командой `volume create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#use-a-volume-driver).

Comment: Volume могут создаваться без ведома оператора (VOLUME в докерфайле), насколько понимаю, главный вопрос у автора возникает из-за этого - образ postgres [скидывает](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/bef8f02d1fe2bb4547280ba609f19abd20230180/10/Dockerfile#L126) все неизвестно куда, но автор даже не подозревает, что производится работа с volume, я бы уточнил этот момент, чтобы информация про volume не осталась незамеченной автором.

Comment: интерпретация dockerfile (программой docker) — это и есть запуск контейнера (и даже не одного). конечно, программа docker (как и любая другая программа) может быть запущена и без ведома оператора. но такие терминальные случаи, по-моему выходят далеко за рамки ответа. а по поводу того, что volume может быть указан не только в командной строке, пожалуй, стоит дополнить (я про это совсем забыл, так как ни разу в жизни не пользовался dockerfile-ами).

Comment: Большое спасибо, за разъяснение. Но если не сложно уточните такой момент. Если при команде commit происходит сохранение информации на диск, как я понимаю "внутри" контейнера. То почему при exporte/importe данные не восстанавливаются, если это полный слепок? И тоже самое при save если в архиве все данные о контейнерах?

Comment: @Evgeny, командой commit файловая система контейнера (со всеми имеющимися изменениями) сохраняется в виде *образа* (image). естественно, туда не попадает ни содержимое оперативной памяти процесса (если вы его не завершили), ни содержимое каталогов, примонтированных внутрь контейнера (т.е. volume-ов).

Answer (score 2):

> Хочу выяснить момент с переносом Docker контейнера с данными.

Для переноса сервиса, как парадокс не нужно переносить контейнер, требуется перенести image c которого создается контейнер и volumes.

Распишу пути (под разные ситуации).

**Export / import**

Пример из моего [dockemacs](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/dockemacs/blob/master/.travis.yml#L28-L29):

```
export ID=`docker run --rm -dt "$REPO:$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER" emacs`
docker export "$ID" | docker import - "$REPO:$VERSION"
```

Запускаем **нужный контейнер**.
Экспортим всю файловую систему в новый image (именно **результатом import будет новый image**).

*В моем случае многослойный образ превращается в однослойный с потерей веса.*

**Вывод:** docker cmd (export / import, save / load) не про миграцию данных, а только для изменения базового образа (например при разработке).

**Данные всегда находятся вне образа в docker volumes**.

*Далее, коротко как все таки переносить данные.*

**Для баз, разворачивания с нуля**

- Делаем бекап pg (лучше в формате sql.tar.gz, так можно менять версии pg без проблем)
- Копируем на другой сервер
- Запускаем нужный сервис (чистый volume)
- Восстанавливаем данные из бекапа
- Проверяем

**Для полного восстановления, дублирования всех сервисов, переезда**

- На новом серваке останавливаем докер
- Со старого копируем (предварительно почистив, удалив ненужные volumes) на новый `/var/lib/docker/volumes` (обязательно rsync with `-p or --perms`)
- Запускаем docker, поднимаем все сервисы